# Reducir espacio al cambiar tipo de contenido

Tags: mysql

Tengo una BBDD MySQL donde guardo ficheros y necesito ganar espacio.
Como ya no necesito los ficheros, para reducir espacio cambio el tipo de contenido a:

ContentType = 'text/plain'
ContentEncoding = 'none'

El problema es que el espacio sigue siendo el mismo. Hay forma de que este espacio baje o debo de ejecutar algún otro comando?

Gracias!

Comment: Por reducir el espacio te referis a que cosa?

Comment: si tengo un tamaño X en un campo y lo elimino, deberia de disponer de mas espacio en disco.

Comment: No automaticamente. En general las bases de datos tienen procesos para compactar y eliminar espacio que ya no usan. Tene en cuenta que por eliminar un campo, no se elimina automaticamente del espacio de archivos que usa la db, ya que las mismas tienden a quedarse con ese espacio a proposito.

Comment: y se puede forzar que se vacie?

Comment: Seguro que si! Hay que buscar en la documentacion..